# Adding make targets to default.nix

Tags: makefile, nix

I have a default.nix file that looks like this:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};
stdenv.mkDerivation {
name = "tsm";
src = ./.;
enableParallelBuilding = true;

cmakeFlags = ["-DGTEST_INCLUDE_DIR=${gtest}/include -DBUILD_COVERAGE=ON"];

buildInputs = [gcc cmake gtest glog lcov graphviz doxygen];
```

When I build, I need to invoke `make doc coverage` as well. How do I `make` additional targets?

After scouring google, I tried `makeFlagsArray = ("doc" "coverage")` and `makeFlagsArray = ("doc coverage"). Neither worked.`doc`and`coverage` should not be built every time. That is why I had them build only on explicit invocation from make.

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
buildPhase = ''
   make all doc coverage
'';
```

does the trick. Not sure if this is the ideal approach.

Comment: If you are using cmake, `cmake --build . -- all doc coverage` works too. This makes it work for any generator.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to run in postBuild those make targets.

```
postBuild = ''
  make doc coverage
'';
```

makeTargets or makeFlags only work when using make but that is replaced by cmake.